# How to access the top-level list item element from any level list item element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nested unordered list with an arbitrary number of levels. I want to be able to access the top-level list item element from any level list item element.

Markup

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">Level 1
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">Level 2
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="list-item">Level 3
            <ul class="list">
              <li class="list-item is-selected">Level 4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For example, if I am on the following list item element level:
`<li class="list-item">Level 4</li>` 
I want to be able to access the following list item element using JavaScript:

`<li class="list-item">Level 1</li>`

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
const currentListItem = document.querySelector('.list-item.is-selected');

const parentUlElement = currentListItem.parentNode;


while (parentUlElement && !parentUlElement.classList.contains('list')) {
  parentUlElement = parentUlElement.parentNode;
}

// This will select the `<li class="list-item">Level 1` element.
const levelOneListItem = parentUlElement;
```

```js
const currentListItem = document.querySelector('.list-item.is-selected');

const parentUlElement = currentListItem.parentNode;

while (parentUlElement && !parentUlElement.classList.contains('list')) {
  parentUlElement = parentUlElement.parentNode;
}

const levelOneListItem = parentUlElement;
  currentListItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
   console.log("levelOneListItem", levelOneListItem);
});
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">Level 1
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">Level 2
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="list-item">Level 3
            <ul class="list">
              <li class="list-item is-selected">Level 4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I access the top-level list item element from any level list item 
Note: Te level of the elements is not fixed

Comment: After doing `parentUlElement = parentUlElement.parentNode`, `parentUlElement` is no longer an `ul` element. Did you mean to access the parent of the parent?

Comment: The level of elements is not fictional

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the question. 
I want to access the li element of the first level.

Comment: `document.querySelector("ul:first-of-type li")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `closest()` to find it. Use as selector:

```
 *:not(.list-item) > .list > .list-item
```

This means: find in the path to the current node, the `list-item` whose  grandparent is not a `list-item`.

```js
const currentListItem = document.querySelector('.list-item.is-selected');

const levelOneListItem = currentListItem.closest("*:not(.list-item) > .list > .list-item");

console.log("levelOneListItem", levelOneListItem);
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">Level 1
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">Level 2
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="list-item">Level 3
            <ul class="list">
              <li class="list-item is-selected">Level 4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Whoa, didn't even know closest() existed. Makes the looping of parent nodes completely pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class to find the first list-item that has a descendant list-item that is-selected:

```js
const currentListItem = document.querySelector('.list-item.is-selected');
const levelOneListItem= document.querySelector('.list-item:has(.list-item.is-selected)');

  currentListItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
   console.log("levelOneListItem", levelOneListItem);
});
```

```html
<div class="div">
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">Level 1
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">Level 2
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="list-item">Level 3
            <ul class="list">
              <li class="list-item is-selected">Level 4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your requirement to access the first `li` in the `ul` ***from*** any level within the `ul` is not the correct way to think about this.

Why can't you just select the first `li` within the `ul` ***from*** the beginning of the document?

```js
// Get the first <li> with a class of "list-item" within the first <ul> with a class of "list".
const firstLI = document.querySelector("ul.list > li.list-item");

// Verify results:
console.log(firstLI.outerHTML);
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">Level 1
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">Level 2
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="list-item">Level 3
            <ul class="list">
              <li class="list-item is-selected">Level 4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You still need to check it has an is-selected descendant. If it was always the first list-item on the entire page, the question would be pointless.